# En-dash converts to hyphen when using Maven ScmProvider.list method

Tags: java, maven-scm, collabnet

The file object in Java is not supporting the character en-dash '–' (unicode `\u2013`). It is automatically converting the en-dash character to hyphen '-' (unicode `\u002D`).

I am using the [ScmProvider.list](http://maven.apache.org/scm/apidocs/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/ScmProvider.html#list%28org.apache.maven.scm.repository.ScmRepository,%20org.apache.maven.scm.ScmFileSet,%20boolean,%20org.apache.maven.scm.ScmVersion%29) method:

```
ListScmResult list(ScmRepository repository, ScmFileSet fileSet, 
                      boolean recursive, ScmVersion version)
```

> List each element (files and directories) of fileSet as they exist in the repository.

In File set, one of the items (SCM File) has the repo item with en-dash replaced with normal hyphen.

I am using Java version 1.6. Is there any limitation regarding this?

Comment: After some Googling, I believe you are using [this method](http://maven.apache.org/scm/apidocs/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/ScmProvider.html#list%28org.apache.maven.scm.repository.ScmRepository,%20org.apache.maven.scm.ScmFileSet,%20boolean,%20org.apache.maven.scm.ScmVersion%29). Is your question specifically related to how this method works?

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where including something as a tag is not enough; you need to actually mention CollabNet, SVN, etc. in your question. And you should link to the docs, rather than just quoting them.

Comment: Yes I would like to know how this method is working.

Comment: @ruakh - In SVN, en-dash works fine. However, the list method is getting the array list with the items after converting the en-dash to hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you think that `java.io.File` automatically translates the character `\u2013` to a regular hyphen (code `\u002D`)? That's not true, at least not on my Windows 7 machine running Oracle Java 6 update 35.

I tried the following code. It creates two files, with different file names; one with the long dash, one with the regular dash.

```
new File("C:\\Temp\\Hello\u2013World").createNewFile();
new File("C:\\Temp\\Hello-World").createNewFile();
```

So, whatever you see happening is not caused by some automatic conversion or limitation in `java.io.File`.

Comment: The API used which is mentioned in the reply by Mr. Duncan Jones above is getting the array list of files.
One of the file name has the en-dash replaced with hyphen.
Not sure why!